# Bootstrap 3 checkbox - Add space between checkbox and text

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to add a space between the checkbox and the text of a checkbox. How can I add the desidered space between these elements? I added a margin-right but it was not effect.

Here my html code:

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Option 1</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

CSS :

```
.check-space{
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

html :

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="" class="check-space">Option 1</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Give important to css.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the default bootstrap styles for checkbox.

In the below example, I've added padding difference of `10px` from the default style, you can change them accordingly to fix your design.

```
.checkbox label, .radio label {
    padding-left: 30px !important;
}
.checkbox input[type=checkbox], .checkbox-inline input[type=checkbox], .radio input[type=radio], .radio-inline input[type=radio] 
{
    margin-left: -30px !important;
}
```

Comment: @MrScf were you able to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

this is working try it.

```
.checkbox label, .checkbox input[type=checkbox]{
    margin-left: 55px;
}
```